# Use Handler / AsyncTask or any other Component for file upload

Tags: android

I need to implement the following functionality:

i> Multiple files needs to be uploaded sequentially.

ii> When one file is uploaded successfully , the next file in the list needs to start uploading.

iii> I need to implement the progressdialog too with the  percentage of the file upload(getting refreshed).

Need hints/suggestions on how to begin the httpcommunication. Should I use Handler since I need to upload multiple files & also handle retry options incase of upload failure? 
I found out AsyncTask normally works for a single task , so is it worth implementing the above functionality using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have to use `Apache HTTPmime` for uploading multiple files, With this you can upload multiple files at a once no need to make a sequence call of `HttpClient's execute or Post` method just make a one Call of **HttpClient**.

Also you can use `AsyncTask` so you don't need to Maintain Handler for this and you can easily display `progress dialog` while your files are uploading.. (This is my personal opinion choice is yours)